# searching for a value in a list - coldfusion

Tags: list, forms, coldfusion, indexing

I have values saved from checkboxes in a form. There are 5 values.

football, cricket, tenis, badminton, rugby.

When entering the data the user can select any or none of thes values so saved values(as a varchar) are a list like

*football, cricket, rugby*

*cricket, tenis, badminton, rugby*

*football,tenis*

what I would like to do is check for the index to see if it exists, to pre-check the textbox when creating an edit form.

```
<input type=checkbox name=categories value='cricket' checked="checked">
```

Many thanks

Thanks.

R.

Comment: You're saving the values as a list in a varchar field?  Might want to normalize that setup...  Perfect example - what happens when you realize that you misspelled 'tenis'?  Now you have (hundreds, thousands?) of records that have to be updated.

Answer (score 1):

```
<cfset checkedValues = "tenis,badminton">
<cfloop list="cricket,tenis,badminton,rugby" index="i">
  <input type=checkbox name=categories value='#i#'<cfif ListFindNoCase(checkedValues, i)> checked="checked"</cfif>>
</cfloop>
```

Comment: Ugh. Hate CFML tags inside HTML tags.

Comment: @al everett - what would be a better approach then?

Comment: I like to create a utility UDF called `checkIf`. It accepts a boolean argument and, if true, returns `checked="checked"` and, if not, an empty string. Then, in my HTML I have `<input type="checkbox" name="categories" value="#i#" #checkIf(ListFindNoCase(checkedValues, i))# />`

Comment: It is, honestly, entirely a style thing. I just find CFML tags embedded in HTML tags hard to read.